# Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools" for Python module installing

Tags: python

I installed VS build tools, but it didn't help. What should I do? [Packeges I installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Nc2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isin't what python wants ( I think so). Download The Build Tools from [HERE](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe).
(This worked for me)