# Error while installing "Louvain" package in python

Tags: python, windows, package

I installed all the requirements for the package "Louvain" on windows. Unfortunately, I confronted the following error. Is there any way to get rid of it and install this package normally?

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:   command:
>   'c:\users\javadht\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setupt
>   ols, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'C:\Users\Javadht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip
>   install-aymgv31c\louvain\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Javadht\App ata\Local\Temp\pip-install-aymgv31c\louvain\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokeni
>   e, '"'"'open'"'"',
>   open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\
>   '"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Javadht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-5hc6g3an'
>         cwd: C:\Users\Javadht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aymgv31c\louvain\ 
>   Complete output (52 lines):  running bdist_wheel  running build 
>   running build_py  creating build  creating build\lib.win32-3.6 
>   creating build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain  copying src\functions.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain  copying src\Optimiser.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain  copying src\VertexPartition.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain  copying src_version.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain  copying src__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain  Fixing
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain\functions.py
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain\Op imiser.py
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain\VertexPartition.py build\lib.win32-3.6\lo
>   vain_version.py build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain__init__.py  Skipping
>   optional fixer: buffer  Skipping optional fixer: idioms  Skipping
>   optional fixer: set_literal  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma  Fixing
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain\functions.py
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain\Op imiser.py
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain\VertexPartition.py build\lib.win32-3.6\lo
>   vain_version.py build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain__init__.py  Skipping
>   optional fixer: buffer  Skipping optional fixer: idioms  Skipping
>   optional fixer: set_literal  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma 
>   UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain/_version.py  set
>   build\lib.win32-3.6\louvain/_version.py to '0.6.1'  running build_ext 
>   Cannot find the C core of igraph on this system using pkg-config. 
>   WARNING: we were not able to detect where igraph is installed on  your
>   machine (if it is installed at all). We will use the fallback  library
>   and include paths hardcoded in setup.py and hope that the  C core of
>   igraph is installed there.
>
> If the compilation fails and you are sure that igraph is installed 
>   on your machine, adjust the following two variables in setup.py 
>   accordingly and try again:
>
> - LIBIGRAPH_FALLBACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ['/usr/include/igraph', '/usr/local/include/ graph']
> - LIBIGRAPH_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_DIRS []
>
>   Build type: dynamic extension  Include path: /usr/include/igraph
>     /usr/local/include/igraph  Library path:  Linked dynamic libraries:
>     igraph  Linked static libraries:  Extra compiler options:  Extra
>     linker options:  building 'louvain._c_louvain' extension  creating
>     build\temp.win32-3.6  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release  creating
>     build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>     Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo / x /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD
>     -Iinclude -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/local/include/igr ph -Ic:\users\javadht\venv\include -IC:\Users\Javadht\AppData\Local\Programs\Py hon\Python36-32\include -IC:\Users\Javadht\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python 6-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE"
>     "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt"
>     "-IC:\Prog am Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared"
>     "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windo s Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program
>     Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt  /EHsc
>     /Tpsrc\CPMVertexPartition.cpp
>     /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src\CPMVer exPartition.obj 
>     CPMVertexPartition.cpp 
>     c:\users\javadht\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-aymgv31c\louvain\include\Graph
>     elper.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'igraph.h':
>     No such fi e or directory  error: command 'C:\Program Files
>     (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN \cl.exe' failed with exit
>     status 2

Comment: Try installing build tools from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041733/error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c/61042006#61042006

Comment: I download build tool. But it still doesn't work.